# VBA taking value from one workbook to another with having formulas pasted

Tags: vba, formula

I am looking to copy the values of specific cells from one workbook to another. I have the code below but it only returns the cells with the formulas and not just the value. I know need to add a line somewhere about pastespecial etc. but not sure where. Any help?

```
    Sub PullClosedData()
On Error GoTo Errorcatch
   Dim filePath As String
Dim SourceWb As Workbook

Dim TargetWb As Workbook

Set TargetWb = ActiveWorkbook


Dim emptyRow As Long

emptyRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)


filePath = TargetWb.Sheets("results").Range("A1").Value
Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)



SourceWb.Sheets("8").Range("D36:G36").Copy 
Destination:=TargetWb.Sheets("Staff data").Range("a" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)



 SourceWb.Close SaveChanges:=False

   MsgBox "Staff data sheet updated"
  Exit Sub
Errorcatch: MsgBox Err.Description
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want values only?

Try changing the line below:

```
SourceWb.Sheets("8").Range("D36:G36").Copy Destination:=TargetWb.Sheets("Staff data").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

To:

```
SourceWb.Sheets("8").Range("D36:G36").Copy
TargetWb.Sheets("Staff data").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).pastespecial xlPasteValues 'Or xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats might suit you better.'
```

You can also assign:

```
destinationrange.value2
 = sourcerange.value2
```

If you only want internal values.